# Turning row-based data into columns by header

Tags: unix, text, file-handling

I have one (fairly large) file, formatted like such:

```
SET1
A B C D E F G

SET2
H I J K L M

SETX
(...)
```

etc.

I would prefer to have them

```
SET1    SET2   SETX
A       H     (...)
B       I
C       J
D       K
E       L
F       M
G
```

Note that the columns are unequally long, and they are not ordered by size. My file is too big to use the `column` function inbuilt in unix, and attempts at getting cute by splicing the file and then pasting it together have had problematic results (that is, it has resulted in the empty columns getting the same content as the separator, which doesn't work for my purposes - they both ended up being "\t"). Note that each set may contain several hundred entries, and I have thousands of sets, making awk impractical (at least with my admittedly limited skills there).

Ideally, the output should be readable in R, but at this point I'd be very happy for something that is practically translatable into R input. Note that I can totally live with this having a non-whitespace separator if that is more practical.

Many thanks in advance for any help! Working in an external linux environment.

Edit:
I also have the file available as

```
SET1
A
B
C
D
E
F
G

SET2
H
I
J
K
L
M
```

If that could make it easier.

Comment: will your data ever have the case where `SET2` would be `H I ... L ' ' M` ? i.e. will there be blanks in it or will it be as you illustrate, one set may be "longer" than the other, with no padding.? Good luck.

Comment: No padding - the letters represent code words, and any overlap would be completely coincidental. Just simple lists separated by whitespace.

Honestly, this is a little embarrassing, I thought I was at least decent enough at this to do simple formatting...

Comment: no worries, just didn't want to try and solve the wrong problem ;-) Actually, it might help to add a small sample list of files and then show the transformed output filelist for same inputs. And, finally, while I'm just getting into 'R', I would expect that it has some functionality that could handle this for you. Add and 'R' tag and see what you get or search for `[R] transform` (there are 4000+ items). Good luck.

Comment: Also, you have specified `unix`. Many of the same tools on the `linux` platform have fewer limitations. Often you can install the `gnu-core` utils to `unix` OR copy your files to a linux machine and see if `columns` now solves your problem. ALSO, please indicate if the final result is 1 big file with all the 1000+ sets in it? AND how big are the file names. If the size of the filename list exceeds the shells command-line buffer size, this will be even tricker to solve. Good luck.

Comment: Columns doesn't work, I've tried that. It's one big file, and columns (and certain other tools) run out of memory when I try to deal with it - this is part of my frustration, my file is too big to use what I normally use in these cases. I've jerry-rigged a solution by myself, using awk on the second dataset and then pasting them together using a shellscript. Would *really* prefer a more elegant solution!

Comment: See my update. I am now using a single file.

Comment: while this is an interesting question for us awkers, I can't upvote it because it  took too many back-and-forths to get a basic understanding of your problem. A good template for this sort of question is 1. Sample input data and file layout, 2. Sample output (and file layout) required. 3. Current code solution 4. Current output with comments about why it is wrong. 5. (optional) mention other things you have already tried and any other observations that will limit peoples time trying to solve your problem. Good luck and keep posting! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess this is more what you wanted:

```
awk -v OFS="\t" 
    '/^SET/ {sets[++cols]=$0; set=$0; max_recs=(c>max_recs?c:max_recs); c=0; next}
     NF{a[cols,++c]=$0}

     END {
        for (i=1;i<=cols; i++) printf "%s%s", sets[i], OFS
        print ""
        for (i=1; i<=max_recs; i++) { 
            for (j=1; j<=cols; j++) printf "%s%s", a[j,i], OFS
            print ""
        }
     }' file
```

For this given input:

```
SET1
B
C
D
E
F
G

SET2
H
I
J
K
L
M
AAA

SET3
A
B
C
D
```

It returns:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '/^SET/ {sets[++cols]=$0; set=$0; max_recs=(c>max_recs?c:max_recs); c=0; next} NF{a[cols,++c]=$0} END {for (i=1;i<=cols; i++) printf "%s%s", sets[i], OFS; print ""; for (i=1; i<=max_recs; i++) { for (j=1; j<=cols; j++) printf "%s%s", a[j,i], OFS; print ""}}' file
SET1    SET2    SET3    
B   H   A   
C   I   B   
D   J   C   
E   K   D   
F   L       
G   M       
    AAA
```

---

#### Previous solution with just one block.

You can use `paste` to show files side by side.

In this case, let's use `head` and `tail` to the get half and half. Then, `xargs` to print one block of text per line. Then they are ready to be `paste`d:

```
paste -d"\t" <(head -2 file | xargs -n1) <(tail -2 file | xargs -n1)
```

For your given input it returns:

```
SET1    SET2
A       H
B       I
C       J
D       K
E       L
F       M
G
```

Comment: The basic sense of the solution works (using paste with a fixed delimiter), but I have several thousand sets in my file, and your solution doesn't really take that into account. I appreciate the effort, and it really helped me out, but I don't think I can accept it as you're not really addressing my general problem.

Comment: No problems. So you have many sets? I understood there were many items in each set. I misread, my fault. Then this could be achieved in `awk`, will see if I can post an update.

Comment: @user3034187 see update with a more generic approach.